# Unwanted padding or margin around buttons in Android

Tags: android, xml

Here is what the app currently looks like when I run it:

[image: Preview app]

As you can see there is some sort of margin/padding around the buttons. I want them to ideally go from edge to edge. I've tried to change the margin, padding, and constraints.

Here is what the XML currently looks like for the two buttons (in a LinearLayout).

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cameraPageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="@string/cameraPageButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/CallPageButton"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/messagePageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/MessagePageButton"
    android:text="@string/messagePageButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cameraPageButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Support Library v7, all the styles are actually already defined and ready to use.

So you can set your button style like this and it will fill all the space

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Simply Override The Default Background With Your Color

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cameraPageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="Camera Page Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are able to modify this behavior in XML. In my personal opinion, you can use a TextView to achieve the same effect. If you need a similar background, (like the default Button itself) you can create a drawable with rounded corners, and if you need a slight shadow too you can add elevation.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:fontFamily="@font/m_bo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="press"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#242424"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />
```